# Don't use wordwrap inside of BB-Code brackets

Tags: php, word-wrap, bbcode

```
[url=http://www.freaking-long-link.com]Unbelievablelongwordsomeonewrotetofuckupyourlayoutsoitneedstobewordwrapped (Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum..)[/url]
```

So.. Is there a way to chunk those layout killers into 20 characters long pieces, each seperated by a whitespace or something, without killing the relevant link around the whole text?

Comment: Do you see the solution here on SO? it's proven to be the most effective in terms of not breaking layout, readability and being straightforward, adaptable and easy to maintain. Why not use that ?

Comment: Hm.. just tried the SO solution and it kinda looks fine.

Comment: ^^ yeah, it's been around for a while... forums have always had issues with content breaking layout, the `overflow:scroll` is straightforward to users

Comment: Does your solution have to be in PHP?

Comment: Nope, not that one with the overflow.. but i still hope, someone will find a regular expression for this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by splitting the word every 20 characters in javascript:

```
        function fixString(s)
        {
            var a = s.split(' ');
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i] = str_split(a[i], 20).join(' ');
            }
            return a.join(' ');
        }
```